# Pass data/parameter to socket thread using VB Net

Tags: vb.net, sockets, .net

am running two TCP servers(one in 50010 and other in 10250) in my code both in separate thread

```
    Private Sub frmMainScreen_Load(ByVal eventSender As Object, ByVal eventArgs As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim Local_PortNum As String = Read_GlobalINI_File("TCP-IP CONFIGURATION", "LOCAL_PORT", "TCPIP_Config")

    Read_FileLocation()
    Dim s As New ClsAutomation_TcpClient
    Dim t As New ClsAutomation_TcpClient

    trd = New Thread(Sub() s.Main()) ' listens 55000 port
    trd1 = New Thread(Sub() t.Main())' listens 10250 port

    trd.IsBackground = True
    trd.Start()
    trd1.IsBackground = True
    trd1.Start()
    End Sub
```

here is my tcpserver class

```
Public Class ClsAutomation_TcpClient
Dim clientsList As New Hashtable
Public WithEvents status_bar1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Sub Main()
    Dim serverSocket As New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 10250)
    Dim clientSocket As TcpClient
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim clientIPAddress As String

    serverSocket.Start()
    MsgBox("Chat Server Started ....")
    counter = 0

    While (True)
        counter += 1
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient()
        Dim bytesFrom(10024) As Byte
        Dim dataFromClient As String
        Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
        networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
        dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
        dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))
        Dim ipend As Net.IPEndPoint = clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint
        clientIPAddress = ipend.Address.ToString()
        clientsList(clientIPAddress) = clientSocket
        broadcast(clientIPAddress + " Joined ", dataFromClient, False)

        ' MsgBox(dataFromClient + " Joined chat room ")
        Dim client As New handleClinet
        client.startClient(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clientsList)
    End While
    clientSocket.Close()
    serverSocket.Stop()
    MsgBox("exit")
End Sub

Sub msg(ByVal mesg As String)
    mesg.Trim()
    MsgBox(" >> " + mesg)
End Sub

Private Sub broadcast(ByVal msg As String, ByVal uName As String, ByVal flag As Boolean)

    Dim Item As DictionaryEntry
    For Each Item In clientsList
        Dim broadcastSocket As TcpClient
        broadcastSocket = CType(Item.Value, TcpClient)
        Dim broadcastStream As NetworkStream = broadcastSocket.GetStream()
        Dim broadcastBytes As [Byte]()
        If flag = True Then
            broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(uName + " says : " + msg)
        Else
            broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg)
        End If
        broadcastStream.Write(broadcastBytes, 0, broadcastBytes.Length)
        broadcastStream.Flush()
    Next
End Sub

End Class






Public Class handleClinet
Public WithEvents status_bar1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Dim clientSocket As TcpClient
Dim clNo As String
Dim clientsList As Hashtable

Public Sub startClient(ByVal inClientSocket As TcpClient, ByVal clineNo As String, ByVal cList As Hashtable)
    Me.clientSocket = inClientSocket
    Me.clNo = clineNo
    Me.clientsList = cList
    Dim ctThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf doChat)
    ctThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub broadcast(ByVal msg As String, ByVal uName As String, ByVal flag As Boolean)
    'Dim Item As DictionaryEntry
    'For Each Item In clientsList
    Dim broadcastSocket As TcpClient
    'broadcastSocket = CType(Item.Value, TcpClient)
    broadcastSocket = Me.clientSocket
    Dim broadcastStream As NetworkStream = broadcastSocket.GetStream()
    Dim broadcastBytes As [Byte]()
    If flag = True Then
        broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(uName + " says : " + msg)
    Else
        broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg)
    End If
    broadcastStream.Write(broadcastBytes, 0, broadcastBytes.Length)
    broadcastStream.Flush()
    'Next
End Sub


Private Sub doChat()
    'Dim infiniteCounter As Integer
    Dim requestCount As Integer
    Dim bytesFrom(10024) As Byte
    Dim dataFromClient As String
    Dim sendBytes As [Byte]()
    Dim serverResponse As String
    Dim rCount As String
    requestCount = 0
    While (True)
        Try
            requestCount = requestCount + 1
            Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
            dataFromClient = _
            dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))
            'MsgBox("From client - " + clNo + " : " + dataFromClient)
            rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount)
            broadcast(dataFromClient, clNo, True)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End While
End Sub
End Class
```

Here what i need to do is send data from a btn_click to the (trd) 55000 instance thread...
how would i do it

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad but in simple terms:

You need to create a [NetworkStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream) object.

Assign this using the [TcpClient.GetStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream) method and then call [NetworkStream.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.write)

Something like this (untested) code:

```
Dim stream as NetworkStream
stream = clientSocket.GetStream
Dim buffer() as byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello")
If stream.CanWrite Then stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
```